# Create a union of two directories, while writing to only it's own original directory

Tags: linux

I want to create a union of two directories and when I move a file within the union'd folder, I want it to stay on the folder it originates from(See below).

How would I accomplish this?  I have tried unionfs, but it will always follow the folder order, for example, if I mount a RW folder in the first spot, all writes will go to that folder, I want the following behavior, as described below:

I want to have 2 RW folders and a union-ed folder

```
RW - driveA
RW - driveB
Unioned - mergeDrive
```

Basically, when I do a file move (I can only touch the files through the `mergeDrive`, I want each file to be moved within there own folder.

So for example,

```
mv /mnt/mergeDrive/subFolderA/fileA.csv /mnt/mergeDrive/subFolderB/fileA.csv
```

FileA's original path:

```
/mnt/driveA/subFolderA/fileA.csv
```

Expected path after move:

```
/mnt/driveA/subFolderB/fileA.csv
```

Then I want to be able to do:

```
mv /mnt/mergeDrive/subFolderA/fileB.csv /mnt/mergeDrive/subFolderB/fileB.csv
```

FileB's original path:

```
/mnt/driveB/subFolderA/fileB.csv
```

Expected path after move:

```
/mnt/driveB/subFolderB/fileB.csv
```

So where ever the root folder of the file originates from, it stays in that root folder when being moved, even though it is moved through `/mergeDrive/`.  Can you setup unionfs(or something similar) to do this?

Comment: Deleting your original question and asking it again is not a good idea...

Comment: @DavidPostill I re-worded it.  I don't understand what is wrong with my question, I have read over the documentation on how to ask a good question, what is your issue with it?

Comment: *shrug* reopened.

Comment: No offense, but you aren't making any sense at all. First you state that the expected path is the folder to which you moved the file but then you state that you want it to stay in its original folder. How do you expect that to happen when you move files? Why move it when you want it to stay where it is?

Comment: @NasirRiley it changes sub directories but the same main path stays the same.  /mnt/driveA/ is constant while /subFolder changes. (and vise versa, for /mnt/driveB/ moves, that stays constant (look again at the examples)

Comment: You still aren't making any sense. If that's what you want to do then why do you need this merged drive nonsense? Just create different subdirectories in one drive and be done with it. If you want to get really cute then use symbolic links.

Comment: @NasirRiley So, I am managing these folders with another program which can only be pointed to 1 directory(No, i can't run this program multiple times).  This program manages these directories.  These directories are actually mounted FTP servers.  I promise you, this is not a XY problem.  If you want me to do a full page write up of why I specifically need what I am asking, I happy to do that, but most people on stackexchange prefer very short responses.

Comment: Then you either need a) different software or b) copy the data from one into the other. I really hope that this isn't in a production environment because it's extremely convoluted and you don't seem to be clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I will give you a long rundown on why neither of those are options A) this is the only software available, nothing can be changed from the software I need a solution that does involve touching the software.  What this software does is single to remote servers to download specific files.  It needs to watch for these files to finish downloading, then move them to a different location while renaming them, then watcher scripts are running in the destination locations to upload these to a Data lake.

Comment: @NasirRiley Now, I can't run multiple instances of this program because a single master instance needs to have and controll all information (sort of a distributed computing environment)

Comment: Then why not just set the application to do it from one location first and then the next afterwards?

Comment: This application can only monitor 1 path and is meant to be automated without any interference.  It is also not "developer friendly" so I can't write a script to change the path config every hour or something.  It sounds like what I am asking for doesn't exist, so I will probably need to rewrite unionfs accommodating for my needs.  Thanks for trying to help though, I appreciate it!

Comment: It might be better to write some scripts to do what you want. You'd have much more control than messing with this app that clearly doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Note: I find this question quite clear and valid, I have already upvoted it few days ago. Unfortunately the only advice I can give you so far is: don't let this criticism you got overwhelm you.

Answer (score 0):

Your doubts are legitimate. I have tested `unionfs-fuse`. It somewhat tries not to move files between branches.

E.g. if a destination directory exists only in the lower branch and I move files residing in the lower branch, then they will stay in this branch.

On the other hand if I deliberately create an empty destination directory separately in *both* branches, then files from the lower branch will be moved to the upper one while moving within the merged mountpoint. I understand this is exactly what you want to *avoid*.

I haven't tested `aufs` nor `overlayfs`.

However I have tested [`mhddfs`](http://svn.uvw.ru/mhddfs/trunk/README). It's a [Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (see [security concerns regarding FUSE](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/security.html)). **`mhddfs` *seems* to work exactly as you want.** Note my tests were limited, I haven't read the code to learn its algorithms to be exactly sure. I think you should test it by yourself. Basic syntax:

```
mhddfs /mnt/driveA/ /mnt/driveB/ /mnt/mergeDrive/
```

In [this article](https://romanrm.net/mhddfs) there's a remark:

> if a certain drive runs out of free space in the middle of a write (suppose, you tried to create a very large file on it), the write process will not fail; `mhddfs` will simply transfer the already written data to another drive (which has more space available) and continue the write there.

At first I thought "the already written data" may refer to another file that would be transfered to make room for the file being written. I guess this would be bad for you. I tried to trigger such behavior and I failed. Now I think "the already written data" refers only to the exact file being written.

In fact I have never in my tests observed `mhddfs` transferring files between two branches. Even if the destination directory existed only in some other branch, the tool duplicated the necessary part of directory tree to the branch where the files were, so they could change their path without being transferred to another branch.

To be clear: I'm talking about tests involving plain `mv`. It's quite obvious if you `cp` to another directory within the merged mountpoint then the resulting copy *may* end up in another branch than the original. Keep in mind [some programs modify files in place, some create copies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37177/108618).

Also note [there's a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mhddfs/+bug/1429402) in the version `0.1.39`. Users report downgrading to `0.1.38` helps. Alternatively you may try this fork: [mhddfs-nosegfault](https://github.com/vdudouyt/mhddfs-nosegfault).